# Create a batch file to login to a UNIX server and cd

Tags: windows, batch-file, unix

I'm trying to create what I thought would be a simple `.bat` file to login to a Unix server and `cd/dir` but I can't seem to get it to do anything past the initial login. What I've tried so far:

```
@echo off
putty -load "servername" -l username -pw pass 
echo cd /usr/frank/ftp/bin
```

Also tried creating a separate file to be called for the `chdir` but it's not calling the other file either.

```
-m C:\Users\Userzed\Desktop\ftp.txt
echo cd /usr/frank/ftp/bin
```

I appreciate any help to show me why this isn't working or point me to where I'm messing this up.

Comment: Windows command processor `cmd.exe` starts `putty.exe` and then waits for the self-termination of this started executable before it reads the next line from batch file and execute it. So your approach cannot work. `cmd.exe` does not communicate with `putty.exe`. Open the help of __PuTTY__ by double clicking on file `putty.chm` in program files folder of __PuTTY__. I recommend to read entire __Chapter 7: Using the command-line connection tool Plink__. Use in batch file `plink.exe` with the options `-load`, `-l`, `-pw`, `-batch` and `-m` with a file containing the commands to run on server.

Comment: PS: It is possible to store in the session settings loaded with option `-load` the login name and a private key file for SSH authentication by private/public key instead of a password and also a remote command to execute automatically after successful connection. Open __PuTTY Configuration__ and look on every configuration setting. Click on button __?__ in title bar left to symbol __X__ and click next on a setting to get displayed the help for this setting.

Comment: PPS: There is at top of every Stack Overflow a search box. Try that search feature with [\[batch-file\] plink](https://stackoverflow.com/search?q=%5Bbatch-file%5D+plink) or [\[batch-file\] putty](https://stackoverflow.com/search?q=%5Bbatch-file%5D+putty). A program/script development is done usually in four phases: 1. __definition of the requirements__, 2. __research__ (searching and reading for existing solutions and documentations), 3. __code writing__, 4. __testing__ (the program/script itself and against the requirements). Programmers forget often 1 + 2 and so 3 + 4 is not done good.

Comment: @Mofi Thanks for the direction! I'll go check out plink :)

Comment: Does `telnet` work for you circumstances?

Comment: @NekoMusume Unfortunately not. Also, I'm having trouble finding plink because it appears that my putty.exe came from a sharepoint site and was just part of the image on my work computer. Looks like I'm going to have to find another way around this issue.

Comment: @Zedu Entering `putty` in any www search engine results in getting displayed first [Download PuTTY - a free SSH and telnet client for Windows](https://putty.org). There can be downloaded the ZIP file containing `putty.exe`, `putty.chm` and of course also `plink.exe`. The ZIP file can be extracted to any directory you want and then all the executables can be used by you. There is no installation necessary. So you can extract `plink.exe` from the ZIP file into same directory as your batch file and reference it with `"%~dp0plink.exe"` in your batch file.